# How to add additional properties while converting array to object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know to convert array to object, we use

```
var object = Object.assign({}, array);
```

I get an array from **multiple select input.** like this

```
var patterns = array["pattern1", "pattern2", "pattern3"];
```

Then after using **object.assign** I get object like this.

```
patterns = {
  0: pattern1,
  1: pattern2,
  2: pattern3
}
```

I want to add more properties and values to the object values like this:

```
   patterns = {
   0:{
      name: pattern1,
      status: 0
   },
   1:{
      name: pattern2,
      status: 0
      }
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is `array["pattern1", "pattern2", "pattern3"];`?

Comment: Patterns is an array made of values received from select [ type = 'multiple' ].

Comment: `patterns.map( i => { name: i, status: 0 } )`

Comment: Error: unexpected token ':'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
var patterns = ["pattern1", "pattern2", "pattern3"];

function parrern_to_objarr(_patterns){
 var out = [];
 for(var key in _patterns){
  var out_obj = {};
  out_obj.name = _patterns[key];
  out_obj.status = 0;
  /* more properties if need... */
  out.push(out_obj);
 }
 return out;
}

console.log(parrern_to_objarr(patterns));
```

Comment: @Mohit Sachdeva  Thanks!